# How to install and configure ftp in docker

Tags: docker, ftp

I am sure there is a way to install ftp in docker but I can't find out how. I looked at other peoples Dockerfile and but their code is very complex. Is there a straight foreword way to install and configure ftp in a Dockerfile?

Comment: Do you want to access the container through ftp and transfer files to it? or do you want to ftp from the container to an external server/location? What's your end goal?

Comment: @Juan I want the container to behave like a ftp server. users should be able to transfer files to and from the container.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`docker run -d -p 20-21:20-21 -p 65500-65515:65500-65515 -v /tmp:/var/ftp:ro metabrainz/docker-anon-ftp`

That's the simpler way to open an anonymous FTP server on ftp://localhost, just replace /tmp for the directory of your preference.

And its Dockerfile looks really simple https://github.com/metabrainz/docker-anon-ftp/blob/master/Dockerfile